# How to resolve this error in Google Data Fusion: "Stage x contains a task of very large size (2803 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB."

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-data-fusion

I need to move data from an parameterized S3 Bucket into Google Cloud Storage. Basic Data dump. I don't own the S3 bucket. It has the following syntax,

```
s3://data-partner-bucket/mykey/folder/date=2020-10-01/hour=0
```

I was able to transfer data at the hourly granularity using the Amazon S3 Client provided by Data Fusion. I wanted to bring over a days worth of data so I reset the path in the client to:

```
s3://data-partner-bucket/mykey/folder/date=2020-10-01
```

It seemed like it was working until it stopped. The status is "Stopped." When I review the logs just before it stopped I see a warning, "Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (2803 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB."

I examined the data in the S3 bucket. Each folder contains a series of log files. None of them are "big". The largest folder contains a total of 3MB of data.

I saw a similar question for this error, but the answer involved Spark coding that I don't have access to in Data Fusion.

[Screenshot of Advanced Settings in Amazon S3 Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJfC7.png)

These are the settings I see in the client. Maybe there is another setting somewhere I need to set? What do I need to do so that Data Fusion can import these files from S3 to GCS?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy the pipeline you are redirected to a new page with a Ribbon at the top. one of the tools in the Ribbon is [Configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilWQl.png).

In the resources section of the [Configure Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h5ZI.png) you can specify the memory resources. Fiddled around with the numbers. 1000MB worked. 6MB was not enough. (For me.)

I processed 756K records in about 46 min.